# Add tags to images uploaded by carrierwave via cloudinary gem

Tags: image, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, cloudinary

In my rails app I'm trying to add tags to images uploaded to cloudinary cloud.

in my carrierwave, ImageUploader class

```
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

 # def cache_dir
 #   "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
 # end
 # 

process :convert => 'jpg'
cloudinary_transformation :quality => 80
process :tags => [ 'tag', model.name]
```

...

I'm trying to add name of the record in tags, but it gives error

```
method 'model' is undefined for class ImageUploader.
```

how can I access value of the field `name` inside my uploader.

I'm new to rails.

please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base  
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  process :convert => 'jpg'
  cloudinary_transformation 
  :quality => 80
  process :assign_tags

  def assign_tags      
    return :tags => ['tag', model.name]      
  end
end
```

You can define any method that returns a hash of parameters. Then you can apply the custom method using the 'process' call. The parameters are passed to the upload API call.